# How do I check if prop is of type array in react

Tags: reactjs

How do I check if received prop is of type array?
I have tried props.data === PropTypes.array ? 
and it does not seem to work
Help me out, someone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not given any context of where you want to do it.

1. To check if a prop is array or not within the component/component-life-cycle methods, you can do

```
if (Array.isArray(props.data)) {
}
```

or

```
if (props.data instanceof Array){
}
```

---

2. If you're taking about the prop-type check, you have to do:

```
arrayProperty: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
  prop1: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  prop2: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  prop3: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  ...other properties of your array
})).isRequired
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification